# I have a Windows hosting and I need to use Wordpress on it

Tags: wordpress, window

I know that this hosting is not the best for Wordpress but unfortunately I can't change it anymore, whenever I try to install a plugin it shows the error "No working transports found" I researched how to fix it and everywhere it shows me to uncomment a php line. ini but I need to fix this on Windows, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to uncomment a line in `php.ini`

You need to:

(1) find the location of `php.ini` in your Windows server,

(2) open the `php.ini` file, search for `;extension=openssl` and uncomment that line by removing the `;`

**Note:** If you're running a PHP version older than 7.2.0, the extension's file name may be `extension=php_openssl.dll` instead of `;extension=openssl` in the php.ini file.

(3) if you’re running PHP as an Apache module, restart the Apache server to make sure the changes are reflected.

**How to Find the Location of php.ini in Your Windows Server:**

To find the location of php.ini in your Windows installation, you will need to run the `phpinfo()` function.

Follow the steps below:

(1) Create an empty file called `phpinfo.php` and place it in your document root,

(2) Edit the file and place the following content in it:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

(3) Save and close the file.

(4) Open the file in your browser and you will see the output of `phpinfo()`.

(5) Search for `Loaded Configuration File` and you will find the location of your php.ini file.

Once you have found the php.ini file, you may then proceed to open it and uncomment `;extension=openssl`.